# Why does my page refresh when I press buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the relevant code of my page :

HTML :

```html
    <button class="ajout-col"><i class="fas fa-columns"> Ajouter une colonne</i></button>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>
                    <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-trash remove-col"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-text-height text-col"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-sort-numeric-down nbr-col"></i></button>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-trash remove-row"></i></button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button class="ajout-lig"><i class="fas fa-list-ul"> Ajouter une ligne</i></button>
```

Javascript :

```js
$('body').on('click', '.remove-row', function() {

    $(this).parents('tr').remove();

});
```

(Any button of the grid refreshes my page, I just put the remove-row one because it's the shortest code only for clarity purpose)

(Issue is located on the second tab, just fill info on the first tab to be able to access the second tab)

Any time I press a button from the grid, it refreshes my page

I searched on google and it appears I have to add "return false" or "e.preventDefault();" to fix the issue, and I tried, but it only fixes partially the issue

If I add any of those at the end of each .on('click'), it fixes the issue for Adding a column or a row
But deleting a row or a column is going to work 1 or 2 times, and then my page is going to refresh again... same for the other buttons (text and number buttons)

Thanks in advance for any help ! :)

```js
// Code goes here

$(document).ready(function() {
    // add row
    $('body').on('click', '.ajout-lig', function() {

        var tr = $(this).parents('.table-content').find('.table tbody tr:last');
        if (tr.length > 0) {
            var clone = tr.clone();
            clone.find(':text').val('');
            tr.after(clone);

        } else {
            var cols = $(this).closest('.table-content').find('th').length,
                tr0 = $('<tr/>');
            tr0.html('<td><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-trash remove-row"></i></button></td><td> <input type="text" class="form-control"> </td>');
            for (var i = 2; i < cols; i++) {
                tr0.append('<td> static element </td>')
            }
            $(this).closest('.table-content').find('.table tbody').append(tr0);
        }
    });

    // delete row
    $('body').on('click', '.remove-row', function() {

        $(this).parents('tr').remove();

    });

    // add column
    $('body').on('click', '.ajout-col', function() {

        $(this).parent().find('.table thead tr').append('<th><button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-trash remove-col"></i></button> <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-text-height text-col"></i></button> <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-sort-numeric-down nbr-col"></i></button> <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left" value=""></th>');
        $(this).parent().find('.table tbody tr').append('<td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>');

    });

    // change column type to text
    $('body').on('click', '.text-col', function(event) {

        let ndx = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
        let inputsCol = $('.table tbody tr td:nth-child(' + ndx + ') input');
        inputsCol.attr("type", "text");

    });

    // change column type to number
    $('body').on('click', '.nbr-col', function(event) {

        var filter = /^[0-9]*$/g;
        var cond = false;
        var min = prompt('Valeur minimum :');
        while (cond == false) {
            if (min.match(filter)) {
                cond = true;
            } else {
                var min = prompt('Valeur minimum incorrect, réessayez :');
            }
        }

        var cond = false;
        var max = prompt('Valeur maximum :');
        while (cond == false) {
            if (max.match(filter)) {
                cond = true;
            } else {
                var max = prompt('Valeur maximum incorrect, réessayez :');
            }
        }


        let ndx = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
        let inputsCol = $('.table tbody tr td:nth-child(' + ndx + ') input');
        inputsCol.attr("type", "number").prop("min", min).prop("max", max);
        //console.log("inputs modified, example:", inputsCol2[0])

    });


    // remove column
    $('body').on('click', '.remove-col', function(event) {
        // Get index of parent TD among its siblings (add one for nth-child)
        var ndx = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
        // Find all TD elements with the same index
        $('th', event.delegateTarget).remove(':nth-child(' + ndx + ')');
        $('td', event.delegateTarget).remove(':nth-child(' + ndx + ')');

    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#btn_login_details').click(function(){

        var error_date = '';
        var error_titre = '';
        var error_entreprise = '';
        var error_conseiller = '';
        var filter = /^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)\d{4}$/;

        if($.trim($('#titre').val()).length == 0)
        {
            error_titre = 'Titre requis !';
            $('#error_titre').text(error_titre);
            $('#titre').addClass('has-error');
        }
        else
        {
            error_titre = '';
            $('#error_titre').text(error_titre);
            $('#titre').removeClass('has-error');
        }

        if($.trim($('#entreprise').val()).length == 0)
        {
            error_entreprise = 'Nom de l\'entreprise requis !';
            $('#error_entreprise').text(error_entreprise);
            $('#entreprise').addClass('has-error');
        }
        else
        {
            error_entreprise = '';
            $('#error_entreprise').text(error_entreprise);
            $('#entreprise').removeClass('has-error');
        }

        if($.trim($('#conseiller').val()).length == 0)
        {
            error_conseiller = 'Nom du conseiller requis !';
            $('#error_conseiller').text(error_conseiller);
            $('#conseiller').addClass('has-error');
        }
        else
        {
            error_conseiller = '';
            $('#error_conseiller').text(error_conseiller);
            $('#conseiller').removeClass('has-error');
        }

        if($.trim($('#date').val()).length == 0)
        {
            error_date = 'Date requise !';
            $('#error_date').text(error_date);
            $('#date').addClass('has-error');
        }
        else
        {
            if (!filter.test($('#date').val()))
            {
                error_date = 'Date invalide';
                $('#error_date').text(error_date);
                $('#date').addClass('has-error');
            }
            else
            {
                error_date = '';
                $('#error_date').text(error_date);
                $('#date').removeClass('has-error');
            }
        }

        if((error_titre != '') || (error_conseiller != '') || (error_entreprise != '') || (error_date != ''))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $('#list_login_details').removeClass('active active_tab1');
            $('#list_login_details').removeAttr('href data-toggle');
            $('#login_details').removeClass('active');
            $('#list_login_details').addClass('inactive_tab1');
            $('#list_personal_details').removeClass('inactive_tab1');
            $('#list_personal_details').addClass('active_tab1 active');
            $('#list_personal_details').attr('href', '#personal_details');
            $('#list_personal_details').attr('data-toggle', 'tab');
            $('#personal_details').addClass('active in');
        }
    });

    $('#previous_btn_personal_details').click(function(){
        $('#list_personal_details').removeClass('active active_tab1');
        $('#list_personal_details').removeAttr('href data-toggle');
        $('#personal_details').removeClass('active in');
        $('#list_personal_details').addClass('inactive_tab1');
        $('#list_login_details').removeClass('inactive_tab1');
        $('#list_login_details').addClass('active_tab1 active');
        $('#list_login_details').attr('href', '#login_details');
        $('#list_login_details').attr('data-toggle', 'tab');
        $('#login_details').addClass('active in');
    });

    $('#btn_gen_grille').click(function() {

            // Générer la grille
            // Ici
    });

    $('#btn_personal_details').click(function(){
        $('#list_personal_details').removeClass('active active_tab1');
        $('#list_personal_details').removeAttr('href data-toggle');
        $('#personal_details').removeClass('active');
        $('#list_personal_details').addClass('inactive_tab1');
        $('#list_contact_details').removeClass('inactive_tab1');
        $('#list_contact_details').addClass('active_tab1 active');
        $('#list_contact_details').attr('href', '#contact_details');
        $('#list_contact_details').attr('data-toggle', 'tab');
        $('#contact_details').addClass('active in');
    });

    $('#previous_btn_contact_details').click(function(){
        $('#list_contact_details').removeClass('active active_tab1');
        $('#list_contact_details').removeAttr('href data-toggle');
        $('#contact_details').removeClass('active in');
        $('#list_contact_details').addClass('inactive_tab1');
        $('#list_personal_details').removeClass('inactive_tab1');
        $('#list_personal_details').addClass('active_tab1 active');
        $('#list_personal_details').attr('href', '#personal_details');
        $('#list_personal_details').attr('data-toggle', 'tab');
        $('#personal_details').addClass('active in');
    });

    $('#btn_contact_details').click(function(){
        var error_address = '';
        var error_mobile_no = '';
        var mobile_validation = /^\d{10}$/;
        if($.trim($('#address').val()).length == 0)
        {
            error_address = 'Address is required';
            $('#error_address').text(error_address);
            $('#address').addClass('has-error');
        }
        else
        {
            error_address = '';
            $('#error_address').text(error_address);
            $('#address').removeClass('has-error');
        }

        if($.trim($('#mobile_no').val()).length == 0)
        {
            error_mobile_no = 'Mobile Number is required';
            $('#error_mobile_no').text(error_mobile_no);
            $('#mobile_no').addClass('has-error');
        }
        else
        {
            if (!mobile_validation.test($('#mobile_no').val()))
            {
                error_mobile_no = 'Invalid Mobile Number';
                $('#error_mobile_no').text(error_mobile_no);
                $('#mobile_no').addClass('has-error');
            }
            else
            {
                error_mobile_no = '';
                $('#error_mobile_no').text(error_mobile_no);
                $('#mobile_no').removeClass('has-error');
            }
        }
        if(error_address != '' || error_mobile_no != '')
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $('#btn_contact_details').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $(document).css('cursor', 'prgress');
            $("#register_form").submit();
        }

    });

});
```

```css
/* Style the header with a grey background and some padding */
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}

.header a {
    float: left;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a.logo {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.header a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.header a.active {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
}

.header-right {
    float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .header a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .header-right {
        float: none;
    }
}

.contenuaccueil {
    text-align: center;
    position : absolute;
    width : 100%;
    color : black;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.background
{
    margin-top : 10%;
    margin-bottom : 10%;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.img
{
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    text-align : center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    color     : #A5A5A5;
    font-family    : "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-size    : 15px;
    font-weight    : 400;
    text-transform   : uppercase;
    text-decoration   : none;
    letter-spacing   : 3px;
}

.box
{
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.active_tab1
{
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#333;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.inactive_tab1
{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: #333;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
.has-error
{
    border-color:#cc0000;
    background-color:#ffff99;
}

/* Styles go here */

.table-content {
    padding: 20px;
}

.form-control {
    width: 90px;
}

/* Style buttons */
.ajout-lig,.ajout-col {
    background-color: DodgerBlue; /* Blue background */
    border: none; /* Remove borders */
    color: white; /* White text */
    padding: 12px 16px; /* Some padding */
    font-size: 16px; /* Set a font size */
    cursor: pointer; /* Mouse pointer on hover */
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Darker background on mouse-over */
.ajout-lig:hover,.ajout-col:hover {
    background-color: RoyalBlue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Innovatech</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/38b99a3f0e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Titre + Menu -->
<div class="header">
    <a href="index.php" class="logo">Innovatech</a>
    <div class="header-right">
        <a href="index.php">Accueil</a>
        <a class="active" href="ajout.php">Nouveau</a>
        <a href="modif.php">Modifier</a>
        <a href="help.php">Mode d'emploi</a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Contenu du site web -->
<div class="contenu">
    <br />
    <div class="container box">
        <br />
        <h2 align="center">Ajout d'un nouvel audit</h2><br />
        <?php echo $message; ?>
        <form method="post" id="register_form">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active_tab1" style="border:1px solid #ccc" id="list_login_details">Informations à propos de l'entreprise</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link inactive_tab1" id="list_personal_details" style="border:1px solid #ccc">Grille d'audit</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link inactive_tab1" id="list_contact_details" style="border:1px solid #ccc">Génération des graphiques</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" style="margin-top:16px;">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="login_details">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Informations à propos de l'entreprise</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Titre de l'audit</label>
                                <input type="text" name="titre" id="titre" class="form-control" />
                                <span id="error_titre" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Nom de l'entreprise</label>
                                <input type="text" name="entreprise" id="entreprise" class="form-control" />
                                <span id="error_entreprise" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Nom du conseiller</label>
                                <input type="text" name="conseiller" id="conseiller" class="form-control" />
                                <span id="error_conseiller" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Date de l'interview (jj/mm/aaaa)</label>
                                <input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="form-control" />
                                <span id="error_date" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div align="center">
                                <button type="button" name="btn_login_details" id="btn_login_details" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Suivant</button>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="personal_details">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Grille d'audit</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="table-content">

                                <button class="ajout-col"><i class="fas fa-columns"> Ajouter une colonne</i></button>
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th>
                                                <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-trash remove-col"></i></button>
                                                <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-text-height text-col"></i></button>
                                                <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-sort-numeric-down nbr-col"></i></button>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-trash remove-row"></i></button>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <button class="ajout-lig"><i class="fas fa-list-ul"> Ajouter une ligne</i></button>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div align="center">
                                <button type="button" name="previous_btn_personal_details" id="previous_btn_personal_details" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Précédent</button>
                                <button type="button" name="btn_personal_details" id="btn_personal_details" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Suivant</button>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--A MODIFIER - PARTIE SUR LES GRAPHIQUES-->
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact_details">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Fill Contact Details</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Enter Address</label>
                                <textarea name="address" id="address" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                <span id="error_address" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Enter Mobile No.</label>
                                <input type="text" name="mobile_no" id="mobile_no" class="form-control" />
                                <span id="error_mobile_no" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div align="center">
                                <button type="button" name="previous_btn_contact_details" id="previous_btn_contact_details" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Précédent</button>
                                <button type="button" name="btn_contact_details" id="btn_contact_details" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Enregistrer</button>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Le pied de page -->
<footer>
    <p>
        Innovatech <?php echo date("Y");?> - All rights reserved
    </p>
</footer>

<script src="jss/ajout.js"></script>
<script src="jss/gengrille.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because they are submit buttons inside a form …? That’s what submit buttons inside a form are _supposed_ to do.

Comment: Default button type inside a form is `submit` so if you dont mention the button type, it will act as submit type and thus it reloads the page. either specify the button type of prevent page from reloading by adding `e.preventDefault()` on fom submit action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because a button with no `type` attribute acts as `type="submit"` and also try to submit the form data to server and refresh the page finally. Please try to set the type to the buttons like `type="button"` for no page refreshes.

```
<button class="ajout-col" type="button">
    <i class="fas fa-columns"> Ajouter une colonne</i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<button class="ajout-lig"><i class="fas fa-list-ul"> Ajouter une ligne</i></button>`
to

```
<button class="ajout-lig" type="button"><i class="fas fa-list-ul"> Ajouter une ligne</i></button>
```

I think this problem is due to, these buttons are actually submitting the form. if we doesn't specify the button type, it will take as a submit type button